# Fabric JS – dynamically change page thumbnail

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas, fabricjs

We are using FabricJS in a multi page environment. Our page list view should use thumbnails that are generated if something is changin on the canvas. Right now we are listening to some object related events and updating the thumbnail on change like this:

```
canvas.on('object:modified', function (option) {

    PagesControllerScope && PagesControllerScope.refreshSavePage();
});

canvas.on('object:moving', function (option) {

    PagesControllerScope && PagesControllerScope.refreshSavePage();
});
canvas.on('object:over', function (option) {

    PagesControllerScope && PagesControllerScope.refreshSavePage();
});
canvas.on('object:out', function (option) {

    PagesControllerScope && PagesControllerScope.refreshSavePage();
});
canvas.on('object:removed', function (option) {

    PagesControllerScope && PagesControllerScope.refreshSavePage();
});
canvas.on('object:rotating', function (option) {

    PagesControllerScope && PagesControllerScope.refreshSavePage();
});
canvas.on('object:scaling', function (option) {

    PagesControllerScope && PagesControllerScope.refreshSavePage();
});
canvas.on('path:created', function (option) {

    PagesControllerScope && PagesControllerScope.refreshSavePage();
});
```

Is there any way to achive something like this in a "general" way without having to define every possible change for the respective object or the canvas itself?

So basically I would like to call my "refreshSavePage()" function everytime something is changed on the canvas or the canvas itsef (size, background etc.) is changed.

I was hoping to use "after:render", but this is simply fired to many times, so this is not an option.

Comment: You no need to save while `moving/over/out/rotating/scalling` after mouseup `object:modified` will fire, so save that time only.

Comment: thanks Durga. I think that I could than just use "text:changed", "text:selection:changed", "object:changed" etc. But how's about changing the canvas size or backgroud. Or sending an object to front an back. Any idea?

Comment: I guess you can call inside your function only where you change or resize background. There is no event firing for that.

Comment: So basically this are all the possibilities I have – right: [https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/Working-with-events]

Comment: @SandorRozsa check if my answer is clear or if you need more details

Answer (score 0):

Create 1 global variable "drawThumb" and add below code in "after:render" method it generate single time thumb

```
clearInterval(drawThumb);
drawThumb = setTimeout(function() {    

// code for generate thumb    

clearInterval(drawThumb);
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any `something is changed` event.

The events that should cover most of the properties are:
`object:modified` keeping also `statefull` to true.

In this case you will catch also color changes.

A better thing you can do is using a combination of debouce and _set.

Your application should really use `object.set('property', value)` to change things inside objects.

At this point you could override `Object.set` to include a debounced version of `refreshSavePage` with an interval that you think is good ( 1 second, half second )

That would mean that many consecutive changes would not fire anything, after the last change, and after the timeout you choose, the function would fire and refresh the thumbnail.